How can I write a custom cop in Rubocop for dealing with one-line class definitions?
Is it possible to write a custom cop that would call out class definitions like this:
MyError = Class.new(StandardError)

And advise the author to format it like this?
class MyError < StandardError; end


RuboCop's development docs should get you started. Or are there any specific problems with matching the dynamic class definition?

Yes, it's certainly possible to write such a cop. What are the issues you are facing with your attempt?

There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues/12343
